# file_get_contents not working for some sites

Tags: php

I'm using file_get_contents to display external content.

It works for most websites but then I came across some it didn't.

Here you can see one where it doesn't: http://www.chusmix.com/game/frame.php?url=iknow.jp/home http://www.chusmix.com/game/frame.php?url=twitter.com

It seems the problem has to do with CSS but I cannot figure out what it is. Also I'm transforming relative paths to absolute ones. However It's not a problem with my code since I tried just the file_get_contents and I still had the issue.

Any ideas of what could be the problem and how to solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a problem with your code.

If you look at the source for that japanese site, you'll notice that the URLs are pointing to `https://iknow.jp/stylesheets/base_packaged.css` but in your frame it's pointing to `http://iknow.jp/home/stylesheets/base_packaged.css`

Notice the extra `/home`? It's probably happening when you do the replacements.

The twitter link you posted works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that site is built on CSS and is not coming along with the fetching.

Answer (score 0):

You are not fetching correct URL for css.

```
Your given Css Path :: http://iknow.jp/home/stylesheets/base_packaged.css

Correct Url :: http://assets0.iknow.jp/stylesheets/base_packaged.css?1303971324
```